# passing Immutable.Maps as props in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

It seems like the immutable library is getting really popular for React. However, I am having trouble using Immutable.Map objects for props. It seems like Immutable.Map does not play nicely with the `...` spread operator which I normally use when components take a lot of props.

```
export class Container extends React.Component {
    const profileProps = {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4,
    };

    // other code adding more keys

    render() {
        return <Profile {...profileProps} />;
    }
}
```

The only method I have for dealing with this is to use `profileProps.toJS()`, and casting back and forth between immutable objects and regular objects defeats the purpose of using the immutable library in the first place. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

No you wont be able to use spread however. You could consider using Records. Though you can't spread them (you'll still need to toJS() to spread them) you still have more goodies than with Maps https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

Records share many methods with Maps and you can access the properties the same way you would do with a normal js object.

From the documentation:

```
const { Record } = require('immutable');
const ABRecord = Record({ a: 1, b: 2 }); // Here you create a record factory
const myRecord = ABRecord({ b: 3 }) // Create a Record using that factory
```

In the Record factory you define the structure of the record and the default values to take in case you don't provide values. On the above example myRecord.a will equal 3
You can then use myRecord the same way you would use a jsObject and you can also access methods that u used to with maps for example:

```
const p = myRecord.get('b') // This will equal 3
const p = myRecord.b // This will equal 3
const {a, b} = myRecord // Will deconstruct
```

So you wont be able to spread them. but you'll be able to deconstruct them. and access properties as you would with normal jsObjects